# How to convert a json file in to parquet using aws lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, parquet

```
s3_obj = s3.Object(s3_bucket, file_prefix)
df= pd.read_json(jsonlines_doc,lines=True)
location=s3_obj.put(Body=json.dumps(jsonlines_doc))
df.to_parquet(location, engine='auto', compression='snappy', index=None)
```

code not working but able to save it locally imported pyarrow and parquet

Comment: Where is the error?  You probably want to look into BytesIO().  You'll need to write to memory or a stream instead of to a local file location.

Comment: unable to write it in S3

Comment: can we write the jsonfile which is in s3 to parquet . tried with glue no luck still

Comment: Please find the error ::  errorMessage": "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      80,
      "lambda_handler",
      "df.to_parquet(location, engine='auto', compression='snappy', index=None)"

Comment: Next time please include the error information in your question so people can more easily help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried saving the file first into the /tmp/ available in lambda and then copy it to the s3 bucket of your choice.

Just to mention Each Lambda execution container provides 512 MB of ephemeral disk space in the /tmp directory, so if your file is bigger than this size you will probably have to use AWS EFS.

Comment: errorMessage": "Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'dict'>",
  "errorType": "ValueError",
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      80,
      "lambda_handler",
      "df.to_parquet(location, engine='auto', compression='snappy', index=None)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675375/how-to-write-the-json-file-in-s3-parquet                        closing this question as i have created another question for my problem